# jQuery or javascript - how show a html page as dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i just created a html page and designed it and its ready to use, 
so what I need to do is to show it as dialog like :

```
$("#alertBtn").click(function(){
    //show dialog
});
```

Comment: Do you mean https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp?

Comment: I think using an iframe is better choice instead of a modal.

Comment: window.open('/page.html', 'name', 'width=700,height=550');

Comment: rymdmaskin, i dont mean about alert ... can i know who and why thumbs down my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a div with a certain ID with all the HTML you want inside. 
For example

```
<div id="dialog"> 
    <p>This is some tekst inside the dialog</p>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS set it's display property to none, like this:

```
#dialog{
    display: none
}
```

In your click function, write the following:

```
$('#dialog').click(function(){
    this.dialog();
});
```

I'm writing this out of my head, so it's possible you'll need to tweak it a little for it to work. If you type 'jquery dialog' into google, you'll also get lots of information like this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_dialog.htm

Or you could try some of the comments, I'm pretty sure they all work too...

**EDIT**
Maybe it's better to initialize your dialog immediately and hide it using the .hide() jquery function. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog();
    $('#dialog').hide();
}
```

When the user clicks your button, you then call the 'show'-function of jquery to show your dialog.

```
$('#someButton').click(function(){
    $('#dialog').show();
}
```

Comment: $("#dialog").. do you mean the div that you wrote above ? and if it not visible how do i click on it ?

Comment: Well, I assumed you had a certain button with a clickhandler, inside that function you can change the display property from none to block...

When you check the documentation, all it says is to use the .dialog() jquery function. But I assume then that the content of your dialog will constantly be visible. 

You could also use the .hide() function (maybe that's even better, I'll edit my answer).